# Global Variables for Worksheet Names

Tags: excel, vba

I need to declare global variables for worksheet names so that if a worksheet name needs to be changed, it can be changed in one spot. This will help to prevent a user from having to dig through each macro to find where each worksheet name was used.

Below is what I have for my global variables. When used this way you get the "Invalid Outside Procedure" for the each of the "Set" instances. I know that the "Set" needs to be inside a procedure but how can I avoid that so that I only have to change the name in one spot for all macros.

`Option Explicit
'Global Variables
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim VB As Worksheet
    Dim DB As Worksheet
    Dim ED As Worksheet
    Dim OC As Worksheet
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim SL As Worksheet
    Set WS = Sheets("WorkSheet")
    Set VB = Sheets("VBA Codes")
    Set DB = Sheets("Dashboard")
    Set ED = Sheets("Extra Details")
    Set OC = Sheets("Occupancy")
    Set SH = Sheets("Shrinkage")
    Set SL = Sheets("SL Impact")`

Just in case what I described above does not make sense. The following is an example:

> Example: I changed the name of a worksheet from "Dashboard" to "Summary". To avoid changing all instances of "Dashboard" in the macros, I only need to change the global variable to "Summary".

Comment: Or just use the codename of the sheet and then no matter what you call it the code will still refer to the correct sheet.

Comment: What do you mean by just use the codename, @ScottCraner? I apologize as I am still fairly new to VBA.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel

Comment: you can also use a const
`Public Const VBA_Codes_WS = "VBA Codes"`
`Sheets (VBA_Codes_WS)`

Comment: Oh so if the Sheet named "Shrinkage" has a code name of "Sheet 7" I would use "Sheet 7"? Then no matter what i change the name to it will still understand to go to "Sheet 7"? @ScottCraner

Comment: Yes for example to gt the value from A1 on that page you would use `Sheet7.Range("A1")`

Comment: Oh so `Sheets("Sheet7").Select` should only be used if "Sheet7" is the actual name of the sheet whereas `Sheet7.Select` is using the CodeName?

Comment: yes and avoid using select. 90% of the time it is not needed and only slows down the code.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!! Learned so much just from that little bit

Comment: I will also add to avoid using `Sheet7` has a code name, because in a few months you will not know what `Sheet7` is. Nor will the person who comes after you. Give it a meaningful name like `ShrinkageSheet` or `Shrinkage`. Will save a lot of aggravation going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Public workbook as workbooks
Public worksheet as worksheets

Have function init.

```
Function init()
Set workbook = thisworkbook
set worksheet = workbook.worksheets("sheet1")
End function
```

Call the init method once in the workbook open sub. The public object  should be sustained for other use.

If you want to show the progress in dashboard follow this tutorial: https://youtu.be/zH8eleVVpm8